# How to write a script which can run the creation of Docker volumes in one command

Tags: docker, shell, sh

In my Docker environment I have always to run the command to create volumes manually like
`docker volume create --name= ...`
I would like a way to speed up this process with a script shell which could help me to run at once.
If I could see a possible solution would be great as I have many volumes to create manually

Comment: I would not re-invent the wheel and I would use a [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) composed of only `volumes` and no `services` definition

Comment: The problem is the Docker stuff is not mine and even in instruction says to do manually I cannot change the setup but maybe I can have something on my side to help me up

Comment: Do you have `docker-compose` installed at all?

Comment: Yes, I have and wheen I run up the docker stuff I received stops asking for create the volumes each time and the volumes are 20 so I'm writing the command 20 times. Do you have a specific command to run with docker compose about it please show

Comment: What trouble are you running into writing the shell script?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to use [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) and have a *docker_compose.yml* file composed only of `volumes` but no `services`:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
volumes:
  logvolume01: {}
  logvolume02: {}
  logvolume03: {}
```

When run, this creates the volumes accordingly:

```
$ docker-compose up                       
Creating volume "docker_logvolume01" with default driver
Creating volume "docker_logvolume02" with default driver
Creating volume "docker_logvolume03" with default driver
Attaching to 

$ docker volume ls 
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               docker_logvolume01
local               docker_logvolume02
local               docker_logvolume03
```

If you need a more complex set of options while creating your volumes, you can find them [in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference).

---

**Just a little quirk to note here**: per default, when you are using `docker-compose`, the volumes will be prefixed with the name of the folder you are in, this is done by Docker so there is no collision between different Docker projects.

This is the reason why, in the example above, the volumes are starting with **`docker_`**, because the folder I am in, is called `docker`.

To fix this, just give a `name` to your volumes:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
volumes:
  logvolume01:
    name: logvolume01
  logvolume02:
    name: logvolume02
  logvolume03:
    name: logvolume03
```

Running this modified version gives:

```
$ docker-compose up                      
Creating volume "logvolume01" with default driver
Creating volume "logvolume02" with default driver
Creating volume "logvolume03" with default driver
Attaching to 

$ docker volume ls 
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               logvolume01
local               logvolume02
local               logvolume03
```